# prototype update() not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, prototype

as the title suggests i have problem with prototype's update function in all IE version but its working in FF and chrome

**this doesnt work**

```
var element = $('mainnav_h');
element.cleanWhitespace();
var html = element.firstChild.innerHTML;
html = html.gsub('<span class="sep"></span>', '');
element.firstChild.update(html);//this doesn't word
```

**but this works**

```
var element = $('mainnav_h');
element.cleanWhitespace();
var html = element.firstChild.innerHTML;
html = html.gsub('<span class="sep"></span>', '');
element.firstChild.update("this works");
```

**source**

```
<div class="innerNavigation_horizontal clear">
    <ul id="mainnav_h">
        <li><span class="sep"></span><a href="#" title="#">items</a></li>
    </ul></div>
```

you can see clearly when i pass variable to update() function is doesn't work in IE where as when i pass string in to it it works in IE, can some one explain this absurd IE behaviour

salman

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem is not with `update()`, but with one of the preceding functions that work on the HTML.

Can you do a test output of html using `alert()` at every stage of the script? Does it contain anything in the first place?

What does `#mainnav_h` look like? Can you post source?

Does `element.firstChild` actually exist? Can you check using

```
alert(typeof element.firstChild);
```

Do you get any error messages in IE?

Comment: alert(typeof element.firstChild); its an object and it does exist i just alert(html) and found out that gsub function is not working in IE, #mainnav_h is a ul id in list and its child are list items, all i want is to delete '<span class="sep"></span>' this from innerHTML of first child of ul im also posting source

Comment: I suspected `gsub` too. How about a simple `replace()` instead? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp Remember you need to submit your pattern as a regex (i.e. escape the special characters).

Comment: replace( /<[^<]+?>\<\/span\>/g,''); i used regular expression and that did the trick as suggested, by the way i also noticed that IE and FF have different approach towards rendering HTML here is an example
IE will display this ( <SPAN class=sep></SPAN> ) whereas FF will display ( <span class="sep"></span> ) note the class name wrapped in double quotes and whole html is in lowercase, one should care for these difference otherwise you regular expression can fail and you wont figure out why its working in FF and not IE and viceversa

Comment: That's basically why one shouldn't use regular expressions or replace operations for HTML in the first place. It would be cleaner to cut out the span using the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the problem was obviously related to HTML casing/syntax, but for other Googlers arriving here, I can recommend disabling IE Compatibility Mode. I could easily recreate the problem in the IE-console (F12) by executing:

Document Mode IE7 standards:

```
>> span = document.createElement("span");
[object] {
    nextSibling : ,
    onresizeend : null,
    onrowenter : null,
    aria-haspopup : "",
    childNodes : [object],
    ondragleave : null,
    oncut : null,
    clientHeight : 0,
    onbeforepaste : null,
    ondragover : null
    ...
} 
>> span.update() 
"Object doesn't support property or method 'update'"
```

Document Mode IE9 standards:

```
>> span = document.createElement("span"); 
[object] {
    nextSibling : ,
    onresizeend : null,
    onrowenter : null,
    aria-haspopup : "",
    childNodes : [object],
    ondragleave : null,
    oncut : null,
    clientHeight : 0,
    onbeforepaste : null,
    ondragover : null
    ...
} 
>> span.update()
[object] {
    nextSibling : ,
    onresizeend : null,
    onrowenter : null,
    aria-haspopup : "",
    childNodes : [object],
    ondragleave : null,
    oncut : null,
    clientHeight : 0,
    onbeforepaste : null,
    ondragover : null
    ...
}
```

This will, of course, only work when running the console on a site that has loaded the prototype framework, e.g. www.redmine.org.